# How to restart Node.Js web app when deployed on Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, pm2

I’m trying to restart a NODE.js web app by itself when the GET request has a certain query parameter like **...?foo=12** . I then pass this foo value to the new instance via NODE.JE process parameter. I got that working without external dependencies(pm2, forever) using the following code:

```
app.get('*', (req:IncomingMessage, res:ServerResponse, next:()=>void) => {
    process.on('exit', () => {
        const cmd:string = process.argv.shift() ?? '';
        const fooValue:string = getFooParameterValue();

        let argv = process.argv;
        if(fooValue){
           argv = [...process.argv, '-foo', fooValue];
        }             

        const argv : string[] = [...process.argv, '-foo', fooValue];
        childProcess.spawn(cmd, argv, {
           cwd: process.cwd(),
           detached: true,
           stdio: 'inherit',
        });
    });
    process.exit();
});
```

Everything works great locally, but when I build an image and run it on docker it wont work. I think that docker container is attached to the 1st instance process, and when I exit this 1st instance the container also stops instead of launching a 2nd instance. My goal here is to have it so I can run the NODE.JS app in a bash process like in I when locally deployed.
If I discard that code and use pm2 everything work as expected and it restarts, but I can't find a way to pass the **...?foo=123** info to the new instance since the NODE.JS process parameter is not applicable. I also tried process.env but i believe is not shared across processes. I have the option of saving in a file as plan "d" but was wondering if this was possible to do in a cleaner way.

Comment: Hi, take a look at this article: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the share. That is ok, but my issue at this moment is not the restart part. Is how i can share state(in this case i need to pass an ID from the 1st process to the 2nd process of my node-js app).

Comment: Hmm, sharing state between instances should be done through a third service such as Redis. Take a look at this article: https://www.bizety.com/2018/08/21/stateful-vs-stateless-architecture-overview/

Comment: Hi, just want when I restart the node.js application to have a process parameter like "node app -foo=1234" and that value(1234) is before I restart the app. Is an ID that i need to load init data for the APP. I know that is not ideal but we can't implement some storage mechanism to save this, between instances

Answer (score 0):

After I think better and investigate a little bit more, I decided in my Dockerfile, beside running my Node.js App, run another process that would prevent the docker container from stop when I restart the Node.Js application.

**Dockerfile**

```
(...)
CMD ["/app/bash-script.sh"]
```

**bash-script.sh**

```
//run Node.js app
npm run start

tail -f /dev/null & 
bash_process_id=$! 

wait $bash_process_id;
```

The advantage of this is that I can use the "child_process" code in the question. To restart the Node.js app and pass by parameter some info. Also I could use process.env.